# Using ZEROMQ and NORM to multicast packets to a large number of WiFI devices

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, network-programming, zeromq, network-protocols

I'm trying to send a file over a wireless network using ZeroMQ and the NORM protocol. I'm currently using the PUB/SUB pattern as that's the only pattern supported by NORM with ZeroMQ as far as I can tell.

I've got it set up so that small messages are passed along just fine, but occasionally the receiver wont pick up a message. From that point messages are just dropped. This can occasionally be remedied by restarting either the Publisher or the Subscriber, but not every time. I've tried adjusting the about of bits sent and the time between each call to send to no avail. It looks like I can receive about 20-60 multicast messages before the connection becomes unstable. If i use the same code but set it up with TCP the connection is much more reliable, on the order of thousands of messages before an error occurs.

I've tried implementing a wrapper class to restart the subscribers after a certain period of inactivity - that didn't work. Neither does setting socket.recv(zmq.NOBLOCK) inside a while loop.

I'm aware of the Pub-Sub Synchronization pattern as described here, http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Node-Coordination, but NORM, as implemented in the ZeroMQ's norm_engine.cpp (https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/src/norm_engine.cpp) doesn't look like it's set up to allow this pattern.

Is there a way to re-send lost packets, or ensure a healthy multicast connection?

Code is Python.

Publisher:

```
import zmq
import time
import os
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.connect("norm://224.0.0.1:3000")
i = 1

imgfile_path = "/home/adam/programs/zmq/tux.svg.png"
imgsize = os.stat(imgfile_path).st_size
print "attempting to send", imgsize, "bytes"

sleep_time = 1
topic = ""
packet_size = 500
left = packet_size
f = open(imgfile_path, 'rb')
fi = f.read(packet_size)
while (imgsize - left) > packet_size:
    print "sent packet number:", i
    print "size: ", len(topic + str(i)[-1] + fi)
    i += 1
    socket.send(topic + str(i)[-1] + fi)

    fi = f.read(packet_size)
    left += packet_size
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
print imgsize, left
time.sleep(sleep_time)
fi = f.read(imgsize - left)
print fi
socket.send(topic + " " + fi)
f.close()
```

Subscriber:

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.bind("norm://224.0.0.2:3000")
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")

imgdir = "/home/adam/programs/zmq/img/"
filename = "tux.svg.png"
destfile = imgdir + filename
packet_size = 501
print "attempting to receive"
f = open(destfile, 'wb')
while True:
    msg = None
    while msg is None:
        try:
            msg = socket.recv(zmq.NOBLOCK)
        except:
            pass
    if msg: 
        print "msg = ", msg[0]
        print "we got something", len(msg)
        f.write(msg[1:])
        if len(msg) < packet_size:
            break
f.close()
print "exiting..."
```

Furthermore, once I can ensure that I can send a file, I'd like to adjust the Forward Error Correction and NACK rate, which is why NORM is so useful to me. Is there a way to do this without re-writing norm_engine.cpp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the things you're assuming are confirmed on the doc page [here](http://zeromq.org/topics:norm-protocol-transport). Namely that, for the time being, it's only PUB/SUB, though you do have the ability to do the syncing you linked by using NORM for PUB/SUB and TCP for REQ/REP.

Otherwise, I believe you're suffering from this still being fairly early in the NORM implementation phase, as (also from my link) it talks about all the things that aren't yet done.  That was from a year ago, but I don't see much out there talking about it since then.

Depending on the specifics of your infrastructure, multicast may not even be the best choice, as discussed [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.zeromq.devel/23460), none of the multicast protocols are really designed for today's high performance network speeds.  It could be that your implementation is falling victim to poor recovery from issues that come up as a natural consequence of these transport protocols.

EDIT:

Per the github link in your post, the code hasn't been updated since 3/19/14, the same date the page I linked above was published, so anything it says about the NORM transport in ZMQ should be completely up-to-date.

At the bottom of the page, in the points about what the ZMQ NORM implementation can and can't do:

1. The current "norm_engine" assumes a fairly specific form of NORM transport options. It may be desirable to expose additional NORM features and transport modalities via the ZeroMQ API. Some examples include:

   - NORM's ability to alternatively provide UDP-like "best effort" and "better than best effort" (using packet erasure coding) delivery services for applications. This would include control of the NORM FEC encoding parameters.

So, it looks like it doesn't (in its current state) give you any control over the Forward Error Correction, just using it in its default reactive (high performance) state.  This *should* provide reliability for your connection by default, but if ZMQs implementation hasn't been thoroughly put through its paces it may be more fragile than you'd like.  With the lack of content and patches out there on it, I'd assume that it's just not ready for you yet.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to push the boundaries of multicast and thought one could stream data this way. Hoping to use NORM's forward error correction to mitigate the speed issue. Have you heard of anything like this?

Comment: Updated my answer with more details around FEC